# Circle consistency on foreign keys SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constants

I have three tables

```
aircrafts 
flights
events
```

`flight` have foreign key `aircraft_id`

`event` also heve foreign key `aircraft_id`
and **optional** foreign key `flight_id`

Are there way to make constrain on `events` to garantie that if `flight_id` is not NULL, than `aircraft_id` on `event` is same as `aircraft_id` on `flight` with this `flight_id` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two constrains

```
ALTER table flights ADD constraint uniq_id_aircraft_id unique (id, aircraft_id);

ALTER table events ADD FOREIGN KEY (aircraft_id, flight_id) REFERENCES event_flights (aircraft_id, id);
```

to get what you want

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the basic business rule. Is it the case that "there are no events needing aircraft that do not also need a flight". If that is the case then just drop aircraft_id from events. However it seems unlikely, i.e. maintenance events do not require flights. So restate the rule as "an event requires either a flight or an aircraft". Make aircraft_id and flight_id **both optional** in events then create a check constraint that requires one to be null and the other not null.

```
create table events
       ( event_id integer generated always as identity  
       , aircraft_id  integer
       , flight_id integer
       , constraint events_pk primary key(event_id)
       , constraint event2aircraft_fk
                    foreign key (aircraft_id)
                    references aircraft(aircraft_id)
       , constraint event2flight_fk
                    foreign key (aircraft_id)
                    references aircraft(aircraft_id) 
       , constraint event_or_aircraft_ck
                    check (   (aircraft_id is null and flight_id is not null)  
                           or (aircraft_id is not null and flight_id is null)
                          )
       )
;
```

Now when an event requires a flight the aircraft_id can only be retrieved from flight.